Only show detail values for selected row in Access 2010 Pivot Table
I have a database and I need to use a pivot table (which I have already created). I am trying to make it so that when a Cell in one of the rows is double clicked (I already know how to get what object in a pivot table was double clicked, so that is not an issue) the details will show.
So I have been able to make the all of the detail rows show when I double click the row object, the problem is that it shows all of them, and not only the one I need. The reason I only need one row is due to future high volume of data (i.e. hundreds of rows).
I have tried using the Watches to track the Details fields, but that has got me going in loops.
My current access form code is as follows:

Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.PivotTable.activedata.hidedetails
End Sub
Private Sub Form_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim PTO As Object
    Set PTO = Me.PivotTable
    Set PTO = PTO.ActiveObject

    If (LCase(TypeName(PTO)) <> "nothing") Then
    On Error GoTo endr: ' ignores errors
        Select Case UCase(PTO.Field.Basename)
            Case UCase("Category 1")
                MsgBox Me.PivotTable.ActiveObject.Value, vbOKOnly ' a test to prove double clicking works on category 1
            Case UCase("Category 2")
'            Me.PivotTable.activeobject.expanded = Not Me.PivotTable.activeobject
            
'                Me.PivotTable.activedata
'                PTO.Data.showdetails
'                PTO.axis.Data.DetailLeft =
'                Me.PivotTable.Selection.showdetails
'                PTO.axis.Data.currentcell.Data.showdetails
'                Me.PivotTable.selection.activedata.showdetails
            
                Me.Requery
                MsgBox Me.PivotTable.ActiveObject.Value, vbOKOnly ' a test to prove double clicking works on category 2
'                Me.PivotTable.activeObject.Field.DataField
'                Me.Detail.Visible = Not Me.Detail.Visible
            Case Else
        End Select
    End If

endr:
    Set PTO = Nothing

End Sub

Table Definition:



Field
Type




Unique Key
Text


Category 1
Text


Category 2
Text


Values 1
Number


Values 2
Number



Sample Data Definition:



Unique Key
Category 1
Category 2
Values 1
Values 2




test 1-1-1
c1
sc01
123
156


test 1-1-2
c1
sc01
156
3857


test 1-2-1
c1
sc02
6576
37357


test 1-2-3
c1
sc03
674698
9876


test 2-0-1
c2
sc10
6476
3753


test 2-1-1
c2
sc11
687
3738



Pivot Table Layout:

The Real Data Has a lot more columns that have different values, the limited values are the result of bare minimum to make an example.
The Main reason I did not use a continuous form with multiple group by sections is  because of the fact that it is not collapsing, and will be immense. Ultimately, the only thing that could meet my criterion of:

Grouping by 2 fields
Total up and summarize data from rows.
Collapse by Grouped field rows.

Edit: Sorry for the poor words, but I genuinely cannot think of a better way to phrase what I am asking.
Edit 2: I am aware that pivot tables are not supported in newer versions. Unfortunately access 2010 is not something I really have a choice in regards to using.
Edit 3: Updated Code, and provided screenshots of access with sample data.
Edit 4: Updated Formatting To include Table Definition and Sample Data As markdown table.

Are you aware that pivot objects have been removed from later versions of Access?

Possibly need to apply filter to the table or query that pivot is based on.

Or maybe set form Filter property.

Testing code. Don't get any intellisense tips. Load event works but DblClk triggers "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. Where did you find code? From Excel docs?

Setting form Filter and FilterOn properties does filter pivot output. Unfortunately, can't find any way to pull value from clicked areas of pivot table.

@June7 I have added images showing samles of the data, and updated the code to show how I got the value of the cell that was double clicked.

If you provide data, it should be as formatted text, not images. https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Purpose of a Pivot Table is to "pivot" data from normalized to non-normalized. Your data shows as already non-normalized. Why use pivot view?

@June7, Sorry I just made up the data quickly as an example of how I set it up.. the reason is mainly due to the fact that in the real data there are summarizations such as averages, totals, as well as percentages which I need to be able to break out. I will add the table asap.

Use clicked field and its value to set form Filter property. I had to use RunCommand to unhide. Could possibly eliminate Select Case. Access is not case sensitive by default so doubt UCase() is needed. Advise not to use spaces nor symbols in naming convention - if you do, brackets are needed.
With Me
.Filter = "[" & .PivotTable.Field.Basename & "]='" & .PivotTable.ActiveObject.Value & "'"
.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdPivotTableShowDetails
End With

A pivot form can be a subform then button on main form can collapse and unfilter pivot form. I named subform container control ctrPivot.
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Me.ctrPivot.Form.PivotTable.activedata.hidedetails
Me.ctrPivot.Form.FilterOn = False
End Sub

